# How to tell pythons numpy where to find liblapack.so.3?

Tags: python, numpy, shared-libraries, suse

So I have to run some python scripts on a cluster with machines for which I have no admin rights. Since numpy was missing, on some of the machines, I created a virtual environment and installed numpy there. I connected to a machine from which I knew it has no python and started the virtualenv python interpreter by `~my_env/bin/python` to check for `import numpy`.

I got this error:

```
# Some trace...
ImportError: liblapack.so.3: File was not found # or something similar.
```

So I made some research on the internet and somebody came up with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. So I added

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/me/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to my `.bashrc` and sourced it. And I put `liblapack.so.3` into `/home/me/lib;`. Now when I try to import numpy I get the error message:

```
ImportError: liblapack.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Now I am stuck. Any ideas what could have went wrong?

The cluster machines have Suse installed on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error means that the format of the `liblapack.so.3` C library differs from the binary format of Python itself. The usual cause for this particular error is having a 64-bit Python but a C library that is 32-bit. You need to have Python and the C library be compiled in the same way.